# CSS multiple brand name slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i was wondering if its possible to make a carousel displaying text instead of images, i tried to make something but it doesn't work well... only displays 1 item at a time, so if anyone can assist me that would be great.

For example i would like to have 8 brand names displayed:

< BRAND 1 | BRAND 2 | BRAND 3 | BRAND 4 >

and after i click the arrow:

< BRAND 2 | BRAND 3 | BRAND 4 | BRAND 5 >

I want to use pure text instead of images.

my current html:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#">JavaScript</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-4">HTML</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-4">CSS</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#">JSON</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#">AngularJS</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

my css for the carousel:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -33%;             }
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%;              }
.carousel-inner .next         { left: 33%               }
.carousel-inner .prev         { left: -33%              }
.carousel-control.left        { background-image: none; }
.carousel-control.right       { background-image: none; }
.carousel-inner .item         { background: white;      }
```

script:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

The problem is right now it displays only 1 item at a time for me, and i would like 4...

Comment: It's working with me here

Comment: Its dispalying more than 1 brand at once? Because for me it shows only 1 and it is replacing each other when i click the next or prev. arrow

Comment: Yes, It displays 3 brand. Why three? depends on the left and right percents and 'col-xs-4'. I also try 'col-xs-3' and reduce the percent, and I get 4 brands

Comment: yes, i know it should be 3 at the moment because of the col-xs-4 and if i change to col-xs-3 then it sohuld show 4,... but the thing is in my chrome and firefox it shows only 1 at a time and when i click next it replaces that one with the next one and i dont know how to fix it, i tohught i made a mistake...

Comment: :) try to place the js below the jquery.js and bootstrap.js --- it really works here both chrome and firefox.

Comment: I have it like that, i always use the same include header, directly from w3schools,...

Comment: pls check this demo: http://www.wwwsitus.com/stackoverflow/carousel.html

Comment: yes that one works fine with me

Comment: nevermind, i found my mistake, thx for the help :)

Comment: if you find it gets successful, answer your own question for future references